# I can't extract text from powerpoint 2003 file by olefile

Tags: python, text, extract

I can't extract text from Powerpoint 2003 ppt. After the following code, python shell will be 'not responding' or hang up.

```
import olefile
ole = olefile.OleFileIO('mypowerpoint.ppt')
text = ole.openstream('PowerPoint Document')
read = text.read()
print(read)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because the stream "PowerPoint Document" contains mostly binary data. So you would need to process it to extract the text before printing it.

Alternatively, you may use print(repr(read)) to see what it contains.